# How to add local file of sqlite \ websql db in cordova + node js + react?

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

Good day!

I'm developing android application using cordova + react js + node js. I have big DB that I want to port in my application. BUT I don't want to create it from file because there will be +- 1 million queries to execute. How can I point cordova \ webSQL on my local DB file, for example, in www folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

To solve this problem I've used https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy & cordova sqlitePlugin.